# ios - in app purchase stuck on "Ready to Submit"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've just submitted my first in app purchase. From some reason the app crashes when a user tries to purchase an item. In itunes connect I see the following status - "Ready to Submit".  How could that be? I  submitted the app and it's approved on the appstore. Why isn't the in app purchase item approved?

Comment: Did you submit the in-app-purchases, too?

Comment: yeah, I did. very strange

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your app you have to submit the In-App purchase from the Version detail page of your application.I think you missed to do this. Once you submit it like this the status of the In-App purchase changed to Waiting For Review.

It might be possible that Apple didn't find your In-App purchase in your application & approved it. Not sure but quite strange.

Comment: So what can I do now?

Comment: Sorry but you again have to re-submit the application. While the application is in Waiting For Review state you can contact Apple for clarification.